# useState referring to stale value

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-state

I have a keeper app where I am adding notes and storing them in database. When I make a post request to the server, I am trying to fetch the _id from database, which will eventually help me to later delete the note ( if needed).
Here is my jsx file

```
function CreateMessage(props) {   

    const [currentGuest, setCurrentGuest] = useState({
        guestName: '',
        guestMessage: '',
        id:''
    });

    function handleMessages(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target;
        setCurrentGuest(prevGuest => {
            return {
                ...prevGuest,
                [name] : value
            };
        });
    }


    function submitMessage(event) {
    //props.onAdd(currentGuest);
    const params = {
      guestName: currentGuest.guestName,
      guestMessage: currentGuest.guestMessage,
    }
    axios
    .post("http://localhost:8000/notes", params)
    .then(res => {
      console.log("The response is"+res.data._id);
      console.log(res.status);
      setCurrentGuest(prevGuest => {
        console.log(res.data._id)
            return {
                ...prevGuest,
                id: res.data._id
            };
        });
        console.log(currentGuest);
    })

    event.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          name="guestName"
          placeholder="Guest Name"
          value={currentGuest.guestName}
          onChange={handleMessages}
        />
        <textarea
          name="guestMessage"
          placeholder="Write a Message"
          rows="3"
          value={currentGuest.guestMessage}
          onChange={handleMessages}
        />
        <button onClick={submitMessage}>Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );

}
```

The id is properly being fetched and displayed in ```console.log("The response is"+res.data._id"). But on first submit, the is always empty and stale id gets attached to the currentGuest object on next submit

Comment: the code looks like you are passing a function to setCurrentGuest in the .then(), is that intentional?

Comment: yes, I m trying to fetch the id from the response and use it to set the id in currentGuest object in setCurrentGuest

Comment: shouldn't setCurrentGuest take an object?

Comment: @DonaldP - Both `setState` and `useState` can also be used in a functional way. We do that when the new state depends on the old state.

Comment: ah, I learned something new today, thanks!

Comment: seems like the posted answer might be correct, on submit you spread the id into state, and on second submit you console.log immediately after calling setState, but I assume at that point in time the state hasn't actually updated yet

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately

Answer (score 1):

```
function submitMessage(event) {
//props.onAdd(currentGuest);
const params = {
  guestName: currentGuest.guestName,
  guestMessage: currentGuest.guestMessage,
}
axios
.post("http://localhost:8000/notes", params)
.then(res => {
  console.log("The response is"+res.data._id);
  console.log(res.status);
  setCurrentGuest(prevGuest => {
    console.log(res.data._id)
        return {
            ...prevGuest,
            id: res.data._id
        };
    });
    console.log(currentGuest);
})

event.preventDefault();
}
```

In the above snippet, after getting the response you're correctly changing the state but the problem is with where you're checking the changed state(`console.log(currentGuest)`). You're basically logging before the state is changed.

You can use `useEffect` hook and log the state inside it. This runs every time the `currentGuest` Changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(currentGuest)
}, [currentGuest])
```

**Update**

You can use the modified `currentGuest` inside the `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(currentGuest)
  if(currentGuest.id) {
   props.onAdd(currentGuest);
   // You can also reset the state here as follows
   setCurrentGuest({
    guestName: '',
    guestMessage: '',
    id:''
   });
  }
}, [currentGuest]) // You might need to add the necessary dependencies to this array.
```

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh. It indeed gives me the updated value, but like you said. But I actually intend to call the commented method
`props.onAdd(currentGuest)`
when i have the correct id updated in the currentGuest object, and then finally set the currentGuest object to empty again. But if I place it so:
```setCurrentGuest(prevGuest => { 
return {
...prevGuest,
id: res.data._id
}});
props.onAdd(currentGuest);}```
It again gets called even before the id is updated. Is there a way we can manage it? Should I put some timeout?

Comment: Basically what if i just not want to console the object value but also run a few lines of codes when i have the updated id in the object? Where should that kind of code be placed

Comment: @NoopurPorwal - That's exactly when you should use the `useEffect` hook. See my updated answer.